# How can I generate images of basic figures with Perl?

Tags: perl, flowchart, image-generation

I am using [jalava](http://jalava.buildyourownapps.com) library as a diagram drawing tool.

It displays figures as images in order to maintain compatibility with majority of browsers.
When diagram block is being resized a request is being made and new gif image is generated and send to browser.

What I need is generating image of basic blocks, like rounded rectangle, circle, diamond with specified parameters (height, width and color).

I want to do all server-side; my server part is written on Perl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

- [PerlMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/perl-magick.php): "PerlMagick is an objected-oriented Perl interface to ImageMagick"

Or

- [GD](http://search.cpan.org/dist/GD/)

Comment: Thanks Sinan. I'll remember that for the next time I answer a perl tagged question ;)

Answer (score 1):

[Imager](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Imager) is my favorite such tool.